# Is it possible to fill the remaining width?

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to fill the remaining width, for example:

[image: example]

- The black rectangle is the container which got an relative width.
- The green rectangles display a `<div>` or an other element with the css in the code block below.
- The red line shows the end of the right div of the setup with the css below. Like you can see I don't want it to be like that it should fill the remaining space.

So how do I fill the remaining space if all the content is smaller than the container?

---

```css
.wrapper {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:black;
  
  width:100%;
  max-width:600px;
}
.column {
  color:white;
  background-color:green;
  
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="column">
        Short text
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <span>Long text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that, it's usually very simple, but it's entirely dependent on your HTML+CSS. Can you build a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a large number of approaches, one is to float the firsst element and apply `overflow:hidden` on the 'stretch' columns to force it to occupy the remainins space.

```css
.column:first-of-type {
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

.column:last-of-type {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  Short text
</div>
<div class="column">
  Long text
</div>
```

Alternatively...you could use a CSS table:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  display: table-cell;
}
.column:first-child {
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1%;
}
.column:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    Short text
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Long text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The overflow workout great, when using `overflow:visible;` I also tried with `hidden` but that gave me some height issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3bumk/122/)

css

```
/* padding, margin and borders are added for representation only */

.container{
    width: 90%;
    border:5px solid black;
    padding:5px;
}
.first{
    float:left;
    background: #aaa;
    border:5px solid green;
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px;
}
.adjust{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#eee;
    border:5px solid green;
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="column1">
Short div
</div>
<div class="column">
Long Div
</div>
```

in css file you can define

```
.column1{ 
width:40%;
}
.column{
width:60%;
}
```